# Nexus 5 Sudden Reboots and Shutdowns

Tags: nexus-5

I have a nexus 5 for about a year now and recently strange problems began to occur.

The phone sometimes just reboots by itself, even when i don't touch it.
Sometimes a power off button appears on the screen and when i try to do something, the phone turns off/reboots.

I have noticed that the power button has became very sensitive, pressing it too hard to lock the screen would result in the screen being shut off and then turned on again, to actually lock the screen i have to press the power button very very gently.

Yesterday i had to format the phone in order to get it to turn on, it just wouldn't turn on otherwise, i would press the power button as gently as i could, the google logo appeared but it would shutdown a second later...

After formating and reinstalling the os, i was able to turn on the phone and use it, but ten minutes ago the phone shutdown itself and now it won't turn on again...

I don't want to format it everyday, i am really suspicious of the power button and think that the problem is related to it, not only because of its sensitivity but also because i read about similar problem on forums and in most cases people related it to the power button.

What can i do?

Thanks,
Arik

Comment: You may not like it but either choose to get your phone repaired or install an app like [Xposed Additions Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb.pro) to block the power button from sending anything to system. Alternatively, you may change the keylayout of your device so that power button doesn't do anything at all. Both requires root access though. We can create shortcuts or widgets to create functionality that you get using power button.